# Customize Dropwizard HealthCheck response

Tags: dropwizard, health-monitoring

I am using Dropwizard version 0.6.2 .The HealthCheck endpoint returns a response with status 200 regardless of whether any health check fails.Is there a way to configure the app to return a different status in case if any of the health checks fail

Comment: It would help if you posted what you're returning from your healthchecks

Comment: This is not a problem.I do see that the response 500 is returned when health check fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem.I do see that the response 500 is returned when health check fails